# Show that a closed dense set E of R must be R

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

This was a question on my exam and I'm not sure how I'm supposed to prove this. I had the following reasoning:

If we assume E' is not R, then there are points in R that are not in E'. If it is one point, then E' can be represented by the union of open sets, which already contradicts our assumption the E' is closed, but I will continue. Take a to be the point that isn't in E, then $E' = (-\infty,a) \cup (a,\infty)$, if we take the complement of this we get $\mathbb{R}-E = \{a\}$. This is obviously not an open set, therefore E is not closed. This contradicts our assumption that it is closed and dense, therefore E is R.

But this doesn't even use the denseness of E, and it seems really handwavy, so I assume there's a more rigorous way to do this but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Dense means that the closure of $E$ is $\mathbb R$. Closed means that the closure of $E$ is $E$. Thus…

Comment: What is the definition of a dense set?

Comment: We use the definition of dense that given a set E, $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \epsilon > 0, \exists y \in E, E \cap B(y;\epsilon) \ne \phi$.

Comment: Closed means the closure of E is E, thus a closed dense set must have that E is $\mathbb{R}$. It's that simple?

Answer (score 2):

According to the definition that you are using, a set is dense in $\Bbb{R}$ iff each point of $\Bbb{R}$ is an adherent point of the set. If in addition you are using the definition that the closure of a set is the set of all adherent points of the set, then a set is dense in $\Bbb{R}$ iff its closure equals $\Bbb{R}$.

If $E$ is closed in $\Bbb{R}$, then by definition (if you are using) or by proof (if you are using some definition else) we have $E = \overline{E}$; we have $\overline{E} = \Bbb{R}$ by assumption, so $E = \Bbb{R}$.